# "Look" Animation Play Before "Walk" Animation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a basic 2D character animation where the character can move left/right/up/down.  I've got four "look" animations for when the character is standing still and four "walk" animations for when the character is moving.  In my animator, I've got triggers `isStopped` and `isMoving`.  When the character starts moving, I set `isMoving` and when the character stops moving, I set `isStopped`.

Everything's working except for a weird behavior that when I click somewhere for my character to move, he quickly enters the "look" animation for a fraction of a second before changing to the correct "walk" animation.  I can verify this by looking at the Animator window in Unity to see which state is being entered.

As soon as the character begins moving, I set the `isMoving` trigger, and when the character reaches its destination, I set the `isStopped` trigger.  I also have a `facing` integer parameter which I set to 1, 2, 3, or 4 during each update cycle.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7fuC.jpg) is a screenshot of my animation setup.

Why is he entering the "look" animation prior to entering the "walk" animation?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I was setting the `isStopped` trigger twice.  I didn't realize the trigger would stay set until it was consumed by another animation changed.